# 0x24 BSOD error while trying to update using Windows Update System

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod, windows-update

im trying to update my windows 7 x64, using the regular windows update function, but it gives me a `0x24` STOP error, it occures when i try to shut down my computer and start the update screen, it goes for a while then it gives me the error,i cannot update when the pc is on, because before, i got a `0x4e` STOP error while downloading some updates, which made me unable to download anymore updates, this is what WinDbg says about the `0x24` STOP error:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM (24)
    If you see NtfsExceptionFilter on the stack then the 2nd and 3rd
    parameters are the exception record and context record. Do a .cxr
    on the 3rd parameter and then kb to obtain a more informative stack
    trace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000001904fb
Arg2: fffff88008e68d68
Arg3: fffff88008e685c0
Arg4: fffff880014b89f1

Debugging Details:
------------------


EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff88008e68d68 -- (.exr 0xfffff88008e68d68)
ExceptionAddress: fffff880014b89f1 (Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+0x0000000000000121)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000000
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000000

CONTEXT:  fffff88008e685c0 -- (.cxr 0xfffff88008e685c0;r)
rax=fffff8a00a2dd930 rbx=fffff8a02e80d4a0 rcx=fffffa8009383ae8
rdx=0000000000000007 rsi=fffff8a00a67a140 rdi=fffff8a02e80d490
rip=fffff880014b89f1 rsp=fffff88008e68fa0 rbp=fffff88008e69220
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffff88008e69000
r11=fffff88008e68fe0 r12=fffffa800c4e0660 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=fffff88008e69558
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010286
Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+0x121:
fffff880`014b89f1 410fb709        movzx   ecx,word ptr [r9] ds:002b:00000000`00000000=????
Last set context:
rax=fffff8a00a2dd930 rbx=fffff8a02e80d4a0 rcx=fffffa8009383ae8
rdx=0000000000000007 rsi=fffff8a00a67a140 rdi=fffff8a02e80d490
rip=fffff880014b89f1 rsp=fffff88008e68fa0 rbp=fffff88008e69220
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffff88008e69000
r11=fffff88008e68fe0 r12=fffffa800c4e0660 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=fffff88008e69558
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010286
Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+0x121:
fffff880`014b89f1 410fb709        movzx   ecx,word ptr [r9] ds:002b:00000000`00000000=????
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_DEREFERENCE

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  1

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - L

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - L

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000000

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80004d0c100
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80004d0c1c0
 0000000000000000 Nonpaged pool

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+121
fffff880`014b89f1 410fb709        movzx   ecx,word ptr [r9]

FAULTING_IP: 
Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+121
fffff880`014b89f1 410fb709        movzx   ecx,word ptr [r9]

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x24

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9431.0 (debuggers(dbg).130615-1214) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000000000000 to fffff880014b89f1

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`08e68fa0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+0x121


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+121

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Ntfs

IMAGE_NAME:  Ntfs.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5167f5fc

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.18127

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xfffff88008e685c0 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x24_Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+121

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x24_Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefix+121

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x24_ntfs!ntfsfindprefix+121

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {a6c72bb9-607f-2a35-308a-961ac89cecff}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> lmvm Ntfs
start             end                 module name
fffff880`01409000 fffff880`015ab000   Ntfs       (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ntfs.pdb\0842A8FED1C5463FB4078078781F5C622\ntfs.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: Ntfs.sys
    Mapped memory image file: c:\symbols\Ntfs.sys\5167F5FC1a2000\Ntfs.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\Ntfs.sys
    Image name: Ntfs.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Apr 12 11:54:36 2013 (5167F5FC)
    CheckSum:         001A27D8
    ImageSize:        001A2000
    File version:     6.1.7601.18127
    Product version:  6.1.7601.18127
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        3.7 Driver
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntfs.sys
    OriginalFilename: ntfs.sys
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.18127
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.18127 (win7sp1_gdr.130412-0013)
    FileDescription:  NT File System Driver
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Have you ran "sfc /scannow" based on the reported failure its very likely your system image is corrupt.

Comment: Based on the errors where it's unable to read from non-page memory, I would run a memtest.

Comment: @Ramhound : Doing it right away.
Moses : Ran it last week, 9 passes, no errors found.

Comment: @Omarrrio - don't bother with the scan.  Moses makes a good point looking at log again you have a memory problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Moses alright run memtest86 for one hour, gave me 2 passes and 2 errors, [this is an image](http://i462.photobucket.com/albums/qq342/omarrrio/caf242b7-67f2-4dcb-8214-91de1b6deab8.jpg) i picked since i don't know how to retrieve a log file (since i searched and it seems that it doesn't create any).

Comment: @Omarrrio - Start pulling modules out until the error goes away.

Comment: you should run **chkdsk /f** to check for NTFS file system issues.

Comment: @Ramhound What modules ?

Comment: Memory modules...

Comment: have you tried chkdsk?

Comment: @magicandre1981 i did try, but it says it is already used by another process, and asks if i would like to do it after the computer is rebooted, i says yes (Y) but it didn't after i rebooted.

Comment: it should run after reboot. What do you see in the **bootexecute** value in the registry?

Comment: @magicandre1981 `autocheck autochk *`

Comment: this is the default value. I get this line before yours when run chkdsk  **autocheck autochk /p \??\C:**

Comment: so it didn't run the check ?

Comment: no. Add this line and reboot.

Comment: it said that there was a boot check that was planned, then it says that it was cancelled